# Long if..else statement

Tags: c, if-statement

How do I reduce long if..else statement such as this one?

```
if( strcmp( alnumToc, "log") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_log( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "log2") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_log2( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "log10") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_log10( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "sqrt") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_sqrt( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "cbrt") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_cbrt( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "abs") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_abs( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "sin") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_sin( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "cos") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_cos( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "csc") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_csc( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "cot") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_cot( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "acos") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_acos( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "asin") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_asin( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "atan") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_atan( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "cosh") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_cosh( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        } else if( strcmp( alnumToc, "sinh") == 0){
            ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
            mpfr_sinh( num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
            CPYRES( 1);
        }
```

It's not just ugly but also slow. I thought of using hashtable with function pointers. Is that good solution?
Note: there will be some mpfr functions, that take more arguments, so I can't create just one macro.

Comment: This looks like part of a parser, maybe you should use a parser generator like `bison`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Store all of the names and functions in a structure:

   ```
   struct calcRoutine_t {
     const char *name;
     void (*function)(int, int, int);
   } calc_routine[] = {
     { "log",  mpfr_log },
     { "log2", mpfr_log2 },
     { "log10",    mpfr_log10 },
     { "sqrt", mpfr_sqrt },
     { "cbrt", mpfr_cbrt },
     { "abs",  mpfr_abs },
     { "sin",  mpfr_sin },
     { "cos",  mpfr_cos },
     { "csc",  mpfr_csc },
     { "cot",  mpfr_cot },
     { "acos", mpfr_acos },
     { "asin", mpfr_asin },
     { "atan", mpfr_atan },
     { "cosh", mpfr_cosh },
     { "sinh", mpfr_sinh }
   };
   ```
2. Loop over the array and use `strcmp` to locate the correct function:

   ```
   for (i=0; i<sizeof(calc_routine)/sizeof(calc_routine[0]); i++)
   {
       if (!strcmp ( calc_routine[i], alnumToc) )
       {
           ARGNUMCHECK( in, 1);
           calc_routine[i].function (num, stack[j-1], MPFR_RNDN);
           CPYRES( 1);
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   (You can add a flag for 'success' before the `break`, or test if `i == sizeof(calc_routine)  /sizeof(calc_routine[0])` at the bottom.)

This has the *initial* advantage you can add, shuffle, and remove any of the sub-routines at will.

As soon as you decided on a final set of names/functions, sort them once by name and then use `bsearch` instead of this loop. On success, `bsearch` will point to the correct structure member and you can call its associated function right away; on failure, `bsearch` will return `NULL`.

#### Add

As noted in a comment, some functions may need more arguments than 1. This number can be stored in the struct `calcRoutine_t` as well, to be tested in the loop.

Comment: @huocp: during development, it's easier to use a list format that can be changed easily. As soon as the list of strings is definite, `bsearch` is extremely efficient.

Comment: sorry, I missed the bottom part of your answer.

Comment: Number of arguments is variable. What should I do than? Use a wrapper? Union?

Comment: At what point is it important that the number of arguments is variable? In the function call to `calc_routine[i].function (..)`? In that case I'd probably add another argument to the function declaration, which would be a dummy value for one-arg functions.

Comment: (Further thought) If the number of arguments is *highly* variable, you could always store them into an array and provide a pointer to this in the function call. The called function itself needs to 'know', then, how many arguments in that array are to be expected.

Comment: I call functions from mpfr library so it's not that easy to add extra arguments (especially as long as I want to keep library as external dependency)

Answer (score 6):

That is very poor code and indeed it will be very slow. It must be rewritten from scratch.

The fastest possible way is to store all string literals in a sorted array, then use `bsearch` to search through it. Use an array of structs where the string is the search key. You'll have to write your own comparison function for your struct type.

If you find the string you were looking for, call its corresponding function through the function pointer:

```
typedef struct
{
  const char*  STRING;
  func_t       action;
} my_str_thing;

const my_str_thing TABLE [N] =
{
  { "ABC", do_this},
  { "DEF", do_that},
  ...
};
```

A hash table would work out too, but seems needlessly complex for this specific case.

Comment: +1, but I would suggest to make it more clear and organized by co-locating the strings (keys) and function pointer (values) in an array of `struct`.

Comment: Pretty much map all the necessary values to speed up the process

Comment: [Almost identical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268062/most-efficient-way-to-match-a-few-strings-in-c/12277684#12277684) demonstrating bsearch.

Comment: @unwind Much better idea indeed. Thank you, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

The performance issue came from that `strcmp` repeatedly scan the same string over and over again.

If your input data is clean, means no unexpected content in `alnumToc`, you can actually skip lots of characters comparison to gain performance. Try this:

```
switch(alnumToc[0]) {
  case 'a': // abs, acos, asin or atan, you don't have to check beyond alnumToc[1]
    switch(alnumToc[1]) {
      case 'b'
        // deal with "abs"
        break;
      case 'c'
        // deal with "acos"
        break;
      case 's'
        // deal with "asin"
        break;
      case 't'
        // deal with "atan"
        break;
    }
    break;

  case 'l': // log, log2, or log10, "og" is common, no need to check
    switch(alnumToc[3]) {
      case '\0' // terminator of c string
        // deal with "log"
        break;
      case '2'
        // deal with "log2"
        break;
      case '1'
        // deal with "log10"
        break;
    }
    break;
  // you can figure out the rest
}
```

The bottom line is to only scan `alnumToc` once for best performance. If you cannot guarantee `alnumToc` is clean, exhause all `alnumToc[0], [1], [2], ...`.

Comment: Wow! This is a true nightmare.

Comment: It seems to function sort of, like, a binary tree, but then written out in full in code. (I also strongly doubt "performance" was the OP's issue.)

Comment: This code will be very hard to maintain. It isn't even necessarily faster than the `bsearch` method proposed in other answers — you're increasing the code size, which means less cache for other useful things.

Comment: @Gilles, agree it's hard to maintain. But 1) `bsearch` doesn't skip any char, 2) the code size is trivial comparing to cache size in modern cpu.

Comment: @huocp – 1) no, it doesn't, but I could do that using hashtable or trie (which is what you've implemented), 2) no, it isn't – registers and L1 cache are still small. This code would be small enaught if this was the only process running – but it's not.

Comment: I would have expected that the computation done with MPFR would actually be slower than a sequence of strcmp. Otherwise I think that using a switch on the first character as suggested here is the best solution. One level of switch (i.e. switch + strcmp) may be sufficient. To avoid code maintenance problems, such a code could also be generated.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Instead keep all strings in an array.

```
char *strarray[] = {"log", "log2", "blah Blah"};
```

**2.** Run a for loop like

```
for(i = 0; i < NO_OF_STRINGS; i++)
{
    // strcmp
}
```

**3.** Keep *array of function pointers* for mpfr_sqrt, mpfr_acos,..

It will reduce code size.

Comment: How is that better? You improved the readability, but it's the same horribly slow algorithm. Any sane solution should use `O(log n)` lookup.

Comment: @Lundin: In my book, improved readability and less code is already better. Granted, the runtime could be improved too.

Comment: @undur_gongor The OP expressed concerned about the code being too slow. Calling strcmp in a for loop is a naive solution. It might be acceptable for a small amount of items. But then, it's not really hard to write a little bsearch snippet.

Comment: He expressed concern about code size, ugliness and performance. Two of the three problems are addressed by this answer. So it is better in that regard. I don't think this answer deserves a downvote.